# Almost there! How to Hide Rows by Integer?

Tags: vba, integer

I am trying to hide rows in Excel by integer counting in this simple example based on the input from a cell. I can't seem to get my syntax right for the Application.Rows("x:x")Select command.

Here is my example code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim i As Integer
Dim k As Integer

For k = 0 To 1

    i = 2 + k * 20

    If Target.Column = 9 And Target.Row = i And Target.Value = "" Then
        Application.Rows("[i+4]:[i+12]").Select
        Application.Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
        Application.Rows("[i+4]:[i+12]").Select
        Application.Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If

    If Target.Column = 9 And Target.Row = i And Target.Value = "1" Then
        Application.Rows("[i+7]:[i+12]").Select
        Application.Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If

    If Target.Column = 9 And Target.Row = i And Target.Value = "2" Then
        Application.Rows("[i+10]:[i+12]").Select
        Application.Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If

    If Target.Column = 9 And Target.Row = i And Target.Value = "3" Then
        Application.Rows("[i+4]:[i+12]").Select
        Application.Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If

Next k

End Sub
```

Comment: You don't need to `.Select` anything. `ActiveSheet.Rows(...).EntireRow.Hidden = True`

Comment: Also don't use `Integer` for row numbers (or anything, really). Maximum value is 32,767 (`2^15-1`) - use a `Long` instead (max value `2^31-1` => fits any worksheet)

Comment: `Rows("[i+4]:[i+12]")` >> `Rows(i + 4 & ":" & i + 12)`

Comment: You also don't need quotation marks around the 1, 2 and 3 in your target values - unless you're reading actual text and need string literals.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`i` means nothing to the Excel calculation engine: it only exists in the VBA runtime context.

So you need to build your string by concatenating *the value of* `i` with string literals, using the *string concatenation operator* `&`:

```
ActiveSheet.Rows(i + 4 & ":" & i + 12).EntireRow.Hidden = True
```

Note the use of an explicit `ActiveSheet` reference, and no need to `.Select` anything - 99% of the time, you never need to work off `Selection`.

Also note, the whitespace between the literal `4` and the `&` operator is very important. This would be a syntax error:

```
ActiveSheet.Rows(i + 4& ":" & i + 12).EntireRow.Hidden = True
```

Because the `&` token also happens to be a *type hint* specifier - an obscure notation that pretty much only exists for backward-compatibility, that you'll want to avoid - but it's good to know that `4&` essentially means `CLng(4)` (i.e. convert the literal `Integer` value `4` to a `Long`).

Comment: @PaulBaird forgot to mention - `&` also dubs as a *type hint* specifier for a `Long`, so `4&` is equivalent to `CLng(4)` - the whitespace on either side (but most importantly on the *left* side) of the `&` operator is *critical* ;-)   (edited) - feel free to mark the question as "answered" by ticking the green hollow checkmark underneath either answer's up/down voting buttons.

Answer (score 3):

With the above statements on how to concatenate the vba with the string we can shorten the code a little with a Select Case.

we can also remove the loop as we only need to know if target.row is two values.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim i As Long
    If Target.Column = 9 Then
        If Target.Row = 2 Or Target.Row = 22 Then
            Rows(Target.Row + 4 & ":" & Target.Row + 12).Hidden = False
            Dim j As Long
            Select Case Target.Value
                Case ""
                    j = 4
                Case "1", 1
                    j = 7
                Case "2",2
                    j = 10
                Case Else
                    Exit Sub
            End Select
            Rows(Target.Row + j & ":" & Target.Row + 12).Hidden = True
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```